# One button click calls javascript first, performs validation and then calls controller method

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a button within a form, which is set to call a controller method. It sends the ViewModel to it as a parameter.
Now I want to make sure that this call to the controller is only made if certain criteria are met on the UI itself (like all required fields are filled etc..)

I want to avoid making call to controller from the javascript, since I don't want to flatten my entire ViewModel.

Comment: Return false if validation fails.

Answer (score 0):

In your JavaScript function, do the validation logic and if it fails, then `return false` to stop the propagation of the click event to the server-side controller, like this:

```
function DoButtonClick() {
    // Perform validation here

    if(!valid)
    {
        // Validation failed, so we want to stop and do not call the server
        return false;
    }

    // Otherwise, validation passed and the controller method will be called
}
```